# Is Product Sans (Google new geometric font) being made available for commercial use?

Tags: font-licensing, google

Will Google's brand new typeface called [Product Sans](https://design.google.com/articles/evolving-the-google-identity/) be available for commercial use like Android's official typeface [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto)?

Comment: I think it'll be available soon. They'll probably add it to the Google fonts library - https://www.google.com/fonts or http://alphabetsrus.com

Comment: You never know with Google, but in general, a typeface designed specifically to be a part of a brand identity is typically *not* release commercially as one doesn't want their brand identity diluted.

Comment: Some specifications https://storage.googleapis.com/g-design/static/product-sans-specimen.pdf

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you open the TTF webfont in use on Google websites, you get some metadata and a link to this URL:
https://www.google.com/fonts/license/productsans

It says:

> Google offers
>   many fonts on open source terms. This is not one of them. Please see
>   www.google.com/fonts.

Comment: You can't get much a clearer [non-] licence than that.

Comment: The only way their intentions could be clearer is if they wrote "If you'd like to know if you're allowed to use this font, our licensing terms are as follows" above a picture of Larry Page flipping the bird.

Comment: Aww, that's unfortunate. I got all excited because I found it online and wanted to use it. Since Google doesn't want anyone using it, I'm not going to post the link here.

Comment: Then I will, in the interest of letting people do what they want and be responsible for their own actions. https://befonts.com/product-sans-font.html